# Multiple properties file in spring

Tags: java, spring, properties

I load a properties file in spring :

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties"/>
```

But if I try to load another file in a different context file I get error.

Comment: can you post the error / exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you need to override properties you can do:

```
<context:property-override location="classpath:override.properties"/>
```

---

OR

if the error is due to not finding a certain property, you can set `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` to true.

---

OR

if the error is about not found resource ( and you're ok with it ), you can set `ignoreResourceNotFound` to true.

---

OR

if there are errors in finding system properties:

The PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer not only looks for properties in the Properties file you specify. By default it also checks against the Java System properties if it cannot find a property in the specified properties files. You can customize this behavior by setting the `systemPropertiesMode` property of the configurer with one of the following three supported integer values:

**never** (0): Never check system properties

**fallback** (1): Check system properties if not resolvable in the specified properties files. This is the default.

**override** (2): Check system properties first, before trying the specified properties files. This allows system properties to override any other property source.

Answer (score 6):

According to the sources you must provide comma separated list of propery files resources. 
This should work for you:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo1.properties,classpath:foo2.properties"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Issue - How to use multiple properties file in spring config ***

1. create seperate prop-files in classPath
   eg. **abc1.properties,  abc2.propeties, abc2.propperties**
2. Create a **propConfig.xml** in class path
      
             class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">

   class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">

   **classpath:/abc1.properties**
                       **classpath:/abc2.properties**
                       **classpath:/abc3.properties**
3. Create combined file for all other beanDefination.xml and propConfig.xml
   **AllSpringConfig.xml**
   3.1 Make sure the below properties configure and locator beans are only defined in one
       fiile i.e. propConfig.xml
   3.2 Make sure propConfig.xml is before any other config files like below

   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">

   ```
   <import resource="SpringPropConfig.xml"/>
           <import resource="abc1.xml"/> <!-- this may use props from abc1.prop --> 
           <import resource="abc2.xml"/> <!-- this may use props from abc2.prop --> 
           <import resource="abc3.xml"/> <!-- this may use props from abc3.prop -->
   ```
4. Use below to initialize the beans
   ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(**"AllSpringConfig.xml"**);

Note - make sure all mentioned files are in classpath or give proper paths where the file is located.